# How to select data from different rows

Tags: postgresql

I want select the opening balance of the first month and the closing balance of the last month in PostgreSQl then now i the sum of income as total income and sum of expenditure as total expenditure on the same row... Here is my data below

```
ID OPENING_BAL INCOME EXPENDITURE CLOSING_BAL COUNCIL_NAME DATE_COMPILED
21   5000.00   1000.00  2000.00   6000.00     BAKONE       2017-04-28
22   6000.00   1000.00  4000.00   9000.00     BAKONE       2017-05-31
23   9000.00   1500.00  2000.00   9500.00     BAKONE       2017-06-30
```

Comment: Please add the expected result.

Comment: Opening balance = 5000 for the first month and closing balance =9500 for the last month..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FIRST_VALUE`/`LAST_VALUE` window functions:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE e (DATE_COMPILED date, OPENING_BAL int, CLOSING_BAL int);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO e (opening_bal, closing_bal, DATE_COMPILED) VALUES
(5000.00, 6000.00, '2017-04-28'),
(6000.00, 9000.00, '2017-05-31'),
(9000.00, 9500.00, '2017-06-30');
```

---

```
SELECT                                                   
  FIRST_VALUE(OPENING_BAL) OVER all_dates_asc,
  LAST_VALUE(CLOSING_BAL) OVER all_dates_asc
FROM e
WINDOW all_dates_asc AS (
  ORDER BY DATE_COMPILED ASC
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
       AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)
LIMIT 1;
┌─────────────┬────────────┐
│ first_value │ last_value │
├─────────────┼────────────┤
│        5000 │       9500 │
└─────────────┴────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: from the previous question i posted last month where i select the opening balance of the first month and the closing balance of the last month, then now i the sum of income as total income and sum of expenditure as total expenditure on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ordering them by desired value and the selecting the first result for example:

```
(SELECT * FROM reconcilation ORDER BY DATE_COMPILED::date ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM reconcilation ORDER BY DATE_COMPILED::date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

if you want just single column you can also select desired columns, but in this case you will lose clarity

```
(SELECT opening_balance FROM reconcilation WHERE council_name = 'BAKONE' ORDER BY DATE_COMPILED::date Desc LIMIT 1) 
UNION 
(SELECT closing_balance FROM reconcilation WHERE council_name= 'BAKONE' ORDER BY DATE_COMPILED::date ASC LIMIT 1)
```

since the data is ordered by date, not by datetime, the query may return inaccurate results if there are multiple entries during the same day, you still can order by both date and id, or just by id, but I would keep id out of it.

```
ORDER BY DATE_COMPILE::date, id ASC
```

Comment: The name of the table is reconciliation and those ones at the top are the fields within the table. (SELECT opening_balance FROM reconcilation WHERE council_name = 'BAKONE' ORDER BY DATE_COMPILED::date Desc LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT closing_balance FROM reconcilation WHERE council_name= 'BAKONE' ORDER BY DATE_COMPILED::date ASC LIMIT 1)... So when I try this select stamen it does not give me the accurate results

Comment: right, because there can be multiple entries on the same day, you can add additional ordering properties like entry id, but i wouldn't order by id myself

Comment: from the previous question i posted last month where i select the opening balance of the first month and the closing balance of the last month, then now i the sum of income as total income and sum of expenditure as total expenditure on the same row..